# Insert to database failed with file attachment

Tags: php

It is the first time I am working with this type of form, and it does not work. I am not an expert.

I have removed some filed for shorten the form, I want the attachment files (3 files) need to uploaded and its name and other also need to be inserted with other form fields.

PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['application'])) 
{
    $branch=$_POST['branch'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $paddress=$_POST['peaddress'];
    $paddress_1=$_POST['peaddress2'];
    $paddressp=$_POST['peaddresspin'];
    $praddress=$_POST['prddress'];
    $praddress1=$_POST['praddress2'];
    $praddressp=$_POST['praddresspin'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $house=$_POST['house'];
    $job=$_POST['job'];
    $income=$_POST['income'];
    $gp_lati=$_POST['loclat'];
    $gp_lngi=$_POST['loclng'];
    $ap_adar = $_FILES['afile1']['name'];
    $ap_pan = $_FILES['afile2']['name'];
    $ap_gran = $_FILES['gfile']['name'];
    $ap_id = $_SESSION['userid'];

    if ($_FILES['file']['size'] <= 20000000) {
        $exp = _get_extension($file);
        $filename = 'image_' . time() . rand(1000, 9999) . $exp;
        $data = array('branch'=>$branch,'gen'=>$gender,'fname'=>$fname,'lname'=>$lname,'peaddress'=>$paddress,'peaddress2'=>$paddress_1,'peaddresspin'=>$paddressp,'prddress'=>$praddress,'praddress2'=>$praddress1,'praddresspin'=>$praddressp,'mobile'=>$mobile,'phone'=>$phone,'house'=>$house,'job'=>$job,'income'=>$income,'loclat'=>$gp_lati,'loclng'=>$gp_lngi,'apadr'=>$ap_adar,'appan'=>$ap_pan,'apgrn'=>$ap_gran);
        $path = '../public/customer/' . $filename;
        $uploadpathBig = '../customer/' . $filename;
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path)) {
            copy($path, $uploadpathBig);
            $resizeObj = new resize($uploadpathBig);
            $resizeObj1 = new resize($path);
            $resizeObj->resizeImage(150,150, 'exact');
            $resizeObj->saveImage($uploadpathBig, 100);
            // $resizeObj1->resizeImage(680,386, 'exact');
            //$resizeObj1->saveImage($path, 100);
            $ins = $con->insert('customer', $data);
            if ($ins == '1'){
                $sucess = '<div class="alert alert-success">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <strong>Well done!</strong>Successfully Inserted Customer.
                            </div>';
                header("location:user.php");
            }else{
                $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <strong>Oops!</strong>Something went wrong try again.
                          </div>';
                header("location:app_ind.php");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

PHP FORM

```
<form class="form-horizontal style-form" name="form1" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return valid();">

    <div class="text_desc">Branch</div>
    <select id="cars" name="branch" >
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="text_desc">Gender</div>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox"  name="gender" value="male"> Male
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox"  name="gender" value="female">Female

    <div class="text_desc">First Name</div>
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <div class="text_desc">Last Name</div>
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    <div class="text_desc">Permanent Address </div>
    <input type="text" name="peaddress">
    <div class="text_desc">Permanent Address Line 2</div>
    <input type="text" name="peaddress2">
    <div class="text_desc">Mobile</div>
    <input type="text" name="mobile" ng-model="user.mobile" onkeypress='return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 )||event.charCode == 43 '>
    <div class="text_desc">GPS : <small>Turn on your mobile GPS and click Track location button.</small>
    <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="loclat" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Location Latitude" />
    <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="loclng" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Location Longitude" />

    Applicant Aadhar
    <input name="files[afile1]" type="file" multiple />

    Applicant Pan Card 
    <input name="files[afile2]" type="file" multiple />

    Grandeur Aadhar 
    <input name="files[gfile]" type="file" multiple />
<button id="btn-signup" type="submit" name="application" value="application" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i> 
    &nbsp Register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Unless I am missing something these `</li>` dont have a matching `<ol>` or `<ul>` and no `<li>`

Comment: What does `valid()` do

Answer (score 1):

Use : `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for upload file

```
<form class="form-horizontal style-form" name="form1" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return valid();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Can you tell me why it was not inserting to the database and with file attachment names. Nothing was inserting to database table.

Comment: Try to change if statement to `if ($_FILES['afile1']['size'] <= 20000000) {`

Comment: Done the all the changes suggested by all , but the code was not working, not inserting to table and uploading image